# Added additional model to models.py, but I get `OperationalError: no such table`

Tags: python, django

My webapp `webapp` has two tables already registered in `models.py`. Let's call them `Model1` and `Model2`. They're built, they work, they're both registered in my webapp's `admin.py` and the entire webapp is running. I can go to the admin console (`/admin`) and see that both the tables are there, and I can look through them.

I wanted to add a third table, `Model3`. I wrote out the code in `models.py` - it looks very similar to the other two models, with slightly different fields. I modified `admin.py` to include it, like the other two. I then deleted the `migrations` folder and I did the following Django commands:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations webapp
Migrations for 'webapp':
  webapp/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Model1
    - Create model Model3
    - Create model Model2
$ python manage.py migrate webapp
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, webapp, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
```

I'm not sure what those migrations are that are actually getting run (I haven't changed `Model1` and `Model2` recently). When I run the webapp and enter the admin console, `Model3` appears along with `Model1` and `Model2`, but clicking on it yields the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/webapp/model3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: webapp_model3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  ... 
  (24 frames omitted)
  ...
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: webapp_model3
```

I also get this type of error when I try to access the model programmatically (*importing* it from `models.py` works fine, but actually accessing `Model3.objects` triggers the error).

I'm sure I've forgotten to do *something*, but I'm at a loss as to *what*.

This is using the default sqlite database that Django provides out-of-the-box. I cannot delete my database altogether - having to repopulate it with the same information it currently has is troublesome for reasons that are not relevant to this question. I can restore from recent backup as much as I want, and I've been doing that as I test solutions to this. In the past, I've been able to make modifications to `Model1` and `Model2` without needing to delete and recreate the database.

---

The contents of the generated `webapp/migrations/0001_initial.py` are:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-11-20 18:55

import webapp.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model1',
            fields=[
                ('key1', models.FloatField(blank=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('key2', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=10)),
                ('key3', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)),
                ('key4', models.TextField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)),
                ('key5', models.ImageField(blank=True, default=None, upload_to=webapp.models.func1)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model3',
            fields=[
                ('NewKey1', models.FloatField(blank=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('NewKey2', models.CharField(default=None, editable=False, max_length=10)),
                ('NewKey3', models.CharField(default=None, editable=False, max_length=100)),
                ('NewKey4', models.TextField(blank=True, default=None, editable=False, null=True)),
                ('NewKey5', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model2',
            fields=[
                ('KeyA', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('KeyB', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)),
                ('KeyC', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)),
                ('KeyD', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)),
                ('KeyE', models.TextField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)),
                ('KeyF', models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to=webapp.models.func2)),
                ('KeyG', models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to=webapp.models.func3)),
                ('KeyH', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('KeyI', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='webapp.Model1')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the content of the migration file `webapp/migrations/0001_initial.py`.

Comment: @heemayl Added the contents of `0001_initial.py`, after anonymizing it to fit with the MCVE

Comment: Okay. Django actually keeps a table to keep track of already applied migrations. So presumably the `0001_initial.py` has already been applied hence Django did not run it. Create a new file e.g. `0002_auto_20191120.py` and put only the `migrations.CreateModel` chunk for `Model3` from the `0001_initial` file. Also put `0001_initial` as a dependency (put inside `dependencies`). Then run `migrate`.

Comment: @heemayl That worked. Specifically, just removing the `_initial` migration file and replacing it with `0001_auto_20192210.py`, which contained only the `Model3` chunk (if I didn't, it gave me an error about multiple leaf nodes or something). And then finally running `migrate`. Can you add that as a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses `django_migrations` table to keep track of all the already applied migrations. So presumably the `0001_initial` has already been applied hence Django did not run it on `migrate`.

You need to:

- create a new migration file yourself e.g. `0001_auto_20191120.py`
- put *only* the `migrations.CreateModel` chunk for `Model3` from the `0001_initial.py` file
- put `0001_initial` as a dependency (put inside the `dependencies` list of the migration file)
- run `python manage.py migrate webapp`